# how to draw objects (rect) from a file

Tags: gnuplot

In gnuplot i can draw a rectangle via

```
set object rect from x0,y0 to x1,y1
```

How to read the coordinates x0,x1,y0,y1 from a file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to put the line of code that sets the rectangle into a separate file and call that file from within the gnuplot script. So you have a file called "coord.txt" that contains the one line

```
set object rect from 2,2 to 4,40
```

and you have a gnuplot script called "rect.gp" that says

```
set title "call rectangle coordinates"
load "coord.txt"
plot x**2
```

If you now from within gnuplot type `load "rect.gp"` you get your graph with the rectangle.

That may not be exactly what you are looking for but maybe a first step.

Answer (score 1):

I was searching at length for a clear example for this today, since this question still gets returned in a search - here's a decent workaround solution formed by reading a recent [feature request for a simple `with rectangles`](https://sourceforge.net/p/gnuplot/feature-requests/507/) method.

You can use the [`boxxyerror`](http://gnuplot.info/docs_5.5/loc5069.html) plot style to draw 2D rectangular areas from a datafile. For example - with a file formated with columns like so:

#### datafile.dat

```
# x0, y0, x1, y1
0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0
1.0, 0.5, 1.1, 1.0
1.1, 0.5, 1.2, 1.0
1.2, 0.5, 1.3, 1.0
1.3, 0.5, 1.4, 1.0
1.4, 0.5, 1.5, 1.0
1.5, 1.0, 1.6, 1.5
1.6, 1.0, 1.7, 1.5
1.7, 1.0, 1.8, 1.5
1.8, 1.0, 1.9, 1.5
1.9, 1.0, 2.0, 1.5
2.0, 1.0, 3.0, 2.0
```

You can plot it like this using the 6 parameter form:

```
plot 'datafile.dat' using (($1+$3)/2):(($2+$4)/2):1:3:2:4 with boxxyerr fill fc "purple";
```

Or like this using the 4 parameter form:

```
plot 'datafile.dat' u (($1+$3)/2):(($2+$4)/2):(($3-$1)/2):(($4-$2)/2) w boxxy
```

[image: gnuplot_rect_via_boxxyerror]

You can also add more data to set the fill color:

> An additional (5th or 7th) input column may be used to provide variable (per-datapoint) color information (see linecolor and rgbcolor variable).

Here's a simple example:

```
rgb(r,g,b) = 65536 * int(r*200) + 256 + int(g*250) + int(b*156); 
plot 'datafile.dat' u (($1+$3)/2):(($2+$4)/2):(($3-$1)/2):(($4-$2)/2):(rgb($1,$3,$4)) w boxxy fs solid 0.50 fc rgb variable
```

[image: gnuplot_rectfill_via_boxxyerror]

Comment: You are absolutely right. The plotting style `with boxxyerror` was available already in gnuplot 4.4.0 (March 2010), probably even earlier. So, I don't understand the currently accepted answer from Dec 2011, the strange answer from 2016 and the feature request from 2020.

Comment: By the way, you could also use the 4 column syntax of `boxxyerror`, e.g. `plot 'datafile.dat' u (($1+$3)/2)):(($2+$4)/2):(($3-$1)/2):(($4-$2)/2) w boxxy`. Check `help boxxyerror`.

Comment: I think `with boxxyerror` can be a little obscure for newer users - since there are more examples for using `set object rectangle`

Comment: I agree. The `boxxyerror` plotting style could also have been named `with rectangle` and users would find it more easily.

Answer (score -1):

You probably need to store the data from the file into variables, then use these variables to define the locations of objects. The way to do this is **not** straight as far as I know. Please refer to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11211339/gnuplot-store-one-number-from-data-file-into-variable). Good luck!