# How to dynamically display text in Gnuplot?

Tags: streaming, live, gnuplot

Anyone knows how to dynamically display text in gnuplot?

I am live streaming a data/log file, and I can extract the data from the file, with cat, sed, cut, etc. command, and then gnuplot it. It works great.

But I want to show these numbers, so that that these numbers will dynamically display in the plot at certain position.

I tried to use

```
set label "< cat file | grep "Time" | cut -d ' ' -f2 | tr -d ','"
```

But this apparently doesn;t work.

Anyone knows how to set the label as a user defined variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a gnuplot command with the customized text / coordinates outside gnuplot, using cat, set, awk and friends, and save it as a separate text file (`myText.txt`). In your gnuplot script, you could than

```
load( "myText.txt" )
```

this dynamically created command file. See [a somewhat similar situation here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8521824/how-to-draw-objects-rect-from-a-file/8523138#8523138).