# gnuplot store one number from data file into variable

Tags: variables, gnuplot

OSX v10.6.8 and Gnuplot v4.4

I have a data file with 8 columns.  I would like to take the first value from the 6th column and make it the title.  Here's what I have so far:

```
#m1 m2 q taua taue K avgPeriodRatio time
#1  2  3   4   5   6        7        8

K = #read in data here
graph(n) = sprintf("K=%.2e",n) 
set term aqua enhanced font "Times-Roman,18"

plot file using 1:3 title graph(K)
```

And here is what the first few rows of my data file looks like:

```
1.00e-07 1.00e-07 1.00e+00 1.00e+05 1.00e+04 1.00e+01 1.310 12070.00
1.11e-06 1.00e-07 9.02e-02 1.00e+05 1.00e+04 1.00e+01 1.310 12070.00
2.12e-06 1.00e-07 4.72e-02 1.00e+05 1.00e+04 1.00e+01 1.310 12070.00
3.13e-06 1.00e-07 3.20e-02 1.00e+05 1.00e+04 1.00e+01 1.310 12090.00
```

I don't know how to correctly read in the data or if this is even the right way to go about this.

**EDIT #1**

Ok, thanks to mgilson I now have

```
#m1 m2 q taua taue K avgPeriodRatio time
#1  2  3   4   5   6        7        8

set term aqua enhanced font "Times-Roman,18"
K = "`head -1 datafile | awk '{print $6}'`"
print K+0
graph(n) = sprintf("K=%.2e",n) 

plot file using 1:3 title graph(K)
```

but I get the error: Non-numeric string found where a numeric expression was expected

**EDIT #2**

```
file = "testPlot.txt"
K = "`head -1 file | awk '{print $6}'`"
K=K+0  #Cast K to a floating point number  #this is line 9
graph(n) = sprintf("K=%.2e",n)
plot file using 1:3 title graph(K)
```

This gives the error--> head: file: No such file or directory
         "testPlot.gnu", line 9: Non-numeric string found where a numeric expression was expected

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have a few options...

**FIRST OPTION**:

use `columnheader`

```
plot file using 1:3 title columnheader(6)
```

I haven't tested it, but this may prevent the first row from actually being plotted.

**SECOND OPTION**:

use an external utility to get the title:

```
TITLE="`head -1 datafile | awk '{print $6}'`"
plot 'datafile' using 1:3 title TITLE
```

If the variable is numeric, and you want to reformat it, in gnuplot, you can cast strings to a numeric type (integer/float) by adding 0 to them (e.g).

```
print "36.5"+0
```

Then you can format it with `sprintf` or `gprintf` as you're already doing.

It's weird that there is no `float` function. (`int` will work if you want to cast to an integer).

**EDIT**

The script below worked for me (when I pasted your example data into a file called "datafile"):

```
K = "`head -1 datafile | awk '{print $6}'`"
K=K+0  #Cast K to a floating point number
graph(n) = sprintf("K=%.2e",n)
plot "datafile" using 1:3 title graph(K)
```

**EDIT 2** (addresses comments below)

To expand a variable in backtics, you'll need macros:

```
set macro
file="mydatafile.txt"
#THE ORDER OF QUOTES (' and ") IS CRUCIAL HERE.
cmd='"`head -1 ' . file . ' | awk ''{print $6}''`"'
# . is string concatenation.  (this string has 3 pieces)
# to get a single quote inside a single quoted string
#   you need to double.  e.g. 'a''b' yields the string a'b 
data=@cmd
```

To address your question 2, it is a good idea to familiarize yourself with shell utilities -- sed and awk can both do it.  I'll show a combination of head/tail:

```
cmd='"`head -2 ' . file . ' | tail -1 | awk ''{print $6}''`"'
```

should work.

**EDIT 3**

I recently learned that in gnuplot, `system` is a function as well as a command.  To do the above without all the backtic gymnastics,

```
data=system("head -1 " . file . " | awk '{print $6}'")
```

Wow, much better.

Comment: Thank you very much! I tried the columnheader method but as you said it does prevent the first row from plotting.  I am now working on the second method you mentioned and I think I can get it to work but I think I'm confused about how to cast the string to a numeric type.  I've added above what I've changed.

Comment: @whatsherface -- You're using a double-quote `"` where you should be using a backtic (located at the same button as ~ on an American keyboard)

Comment: Ok, I fixed it now.  Just to make sure, there should be double quotes _and_ backtics, is that correct?  When I run it it still gives me the error: Non-numeric string found where a numeric expression was expected referring to line 6 (print K+0).  This would indicate that it's not going to let me cast a string to a numeric type in that way?

Comment: @whatsherface -- It works for me (see my edit for the exact code I used).  (gnuplot 4.4.2, OS X)

Comment: @whatsherface -- In your script, you're never actually storing the result of the cast.

Comment: I used exactly that code but I am still getting this error--> head: file: No such file or directory
         "testPlot.gnu", line 9: Non-numeric string found where a numeric expression was expected  (line 9 reads: K=K+0 and testPlot.gnu is the name of my gnuplot script file)  I will edit above to reflect this.

Comment: Your problem is that in `K=...` you're not passing the datafile name.  You need to explicitly say: `head -1 testPlot.txt`.  (the variable `file` doesn't get expanded here).

Comment: Ok, I've got it working now, thank you very much!  I do have 2 questions though. 1) Is there any way to get around having to explicitly put in the text file's name each time? 2) How should I change this such that it pulls off the 6th entry in the 2nd row rather than the first?

Comment: Alright I think I've got it all up and running perfectly now. Thank you so much for all your help!  I've learned of ton of stuff through this.

Comment: @whatsherface -- I just recently learned a better way to do system call without all the backtic gymnastics.  :-).  I just figured I'd let you know.  (See the final edit above).

Comment: the system call looks great. I just tried it and get the gnuplot error message `')' expected`

Comment: how do I mix `columnheader` with variable. like say `title <iteration_number>: columnheader(2)` how do I do that?

Answer (score 7):

This is a very old question, but here's a nice way to get access to a single value anywhere in your data file and save it as a gnuplot-accessible variable:

```
set term unknown #This terminal will not attempt to plot anything
plot 'myfile.dat' index 0 every 1:1:0:0:0:0 u (var=$1):1
```

The `index` number allows you to address a particular dataset (separated by two carriage returns), while `every` allows you to specify a particular line.

The colon-separated numbers after `every` should be of the form `1:1:<line_number>:<block_number>:<line_number>:<block_number>`, where the line number is the line with the the block (starting from 0), and the block number is the number of the block (separated by a single carriage return, again starting from 0).  The first and second numbers say plot every 1 lines and every one data block, and the third and fourth say start from line `<line_number>` and block `<block_number>`.  The fifth and sixth say where to stop.  This allows you to select a single line anywhere in your data file.

The last part of the plot command assigns the value in a particular column (in this case, column 1) to your variable (`var`).  There needs to be two values to a plot command, so I chose column 1 to plot against my variable assignment statement.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a less 'awk'-ward solution which assigns the value from the first row and 6th column of the file 'Data.txt' to the variable x16.

```
set table
# Syntax: u 0:($0==RowIndex?(VariableName=$ColumnIndex):$ColumnIndex)
# RowIndex starts with 0, ColumnIndex starts with 1
# 'u' is an abbreviation for the 'using' modifier 
plot 'Data.txt' u 0:($0==0?(x16=$6):$6)
unset table
```

A more general example for storing several values is given below:

```
# Load data from file to variable
# Gnuplot can only access the data via the "plot" command
set table
# Syntax: u 0:($0==RowIndex?(VariableName=$ColumnIndex):$ColumnIndex)
# RowIndex starts with 0, ColumnIndex starts with 1
# 'u' is an abbreviation for the 'using' modifier 
# Example: Assign all values according to: xij = Data33[i,j]; i,j = 1,2,3
plot 'Data33.txt' u 0:($0==0?(x11=$1):$1),\
                '' u 0:($0==0?(x12=$2):$2),\
                '' u 0:($0==0?(x13=$3):$3),\
                '' u 0:($0==1?(x21=$1):$1),\
                '' u 0:($0==1?(x22=$2):$2),\
                '' u 0:($0==1?(x23=$3):$3),\
                '' u 0:($0==2?(x31=$1):$1),\
                '' u 0:($0==2?(x32=$2):$2),\
                '' u 0:($0==2?(x33=$3):$3)
unset table
print x11, x12, x13     # Data from first row
print x21, x22, x23     # Data from second row
print x31, x32, x33     # Data from third row
```