# Shell, Gnuplot : Set title from variable in file

Tags: linux, shell, gnuplot

I would like the title of my graphic to be a numeric variable present in a file. The same file where there are the variables that I use for the plot.

**for example :**

```
set title sprintf("Nu=f(t) avec Ra=%d",titre)
```

Where the titre variable is the second line of the first column of my file.
I don't know how to assign this value to titre variable.

I need help, please.

Thank you

Comment: Try `titre = system("awk 'NR==2 {print $1}' myfile.txt")`

Comment: Have a look here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/11213334/2836621

Comment: it works, thanks a lot !